# IBAction does work whereas if statement inside it does not

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement

I am creating a simple app in which I tap a button, and an integer is randomly generated. if this integer is 0 then the user gets a point if not then a UILabel says something. It recognizes when the button is pushed.

```
        if ((ranNumOne = 0)) {
            NSLog(@"hello000000000000000");
            scor++;
            scoreNumber.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", scor];
            thing.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"blah blah"];
        }
        else if ((ranNumOne = 4)) {
            NSLog(@"hello11111111111");
            thing.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"blah blah blah"];
        }
```

Comment: Learn the proper syntax for the equality operator. It's not `=` (that's assignment).

Comment: it should be `ranNumOne == 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in your code, you are assigning a 0 value to ranNumOne through the following statement.

```
if ((ranNumOne = 0))
```

Then the if statement checks for a true condition. But this condition fails since ranNumOne is 0.

Please see the following link to understand the operation precedence and order of expression evaluation in C

[Precedence and Order of Evaluation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bxt6kc4.aspx)

So after the correction, your code will look like as follows

```
if ((ranNumOne == 0)) {
        NSLog(@"hello000000000000000");
        scor += 1;
        scoreNumber.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", scor];
        thing.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"blah blah"];
    }
    else if ((ranNumOne == 4)) {
        NSLog(@"hello11111111111");
        thing.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"blah blah blah"];
    }
```